# How does the DLookup work in this instance?

Tags: ms-access, vba

New user here :)

I got a question about DLookup in the below code. The code is suppose to only allow a selected user to open a form. The user is in the tbl and with the On Error Resume Next the code is working, allowing the user to access the application, however when I comment out the On Error I get the Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch. I was hoping for someone to explain why does it fail with On Error commented out. I understand that If statement requires a condition to evaluate, so how does getting the username allow the application to open the form?

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

On Error Resume Next

If DLookup("[CitrixID]", "tbl_UserAccess", "[CitrixID] = " & "'" & Environ("username") & "'") Then

Else

MsgBox "You do not have permission to access the application"

DoCmd.Close

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really not the way to do this, but I'll explain what it does.

`DLookUp` looks up a value from a table. In your case, it's looking up  `CitrixID` from the table `CitrixID` where `CitrixID` is equal to the username. It then returns that username as the condition for that `If` statement.

An `If` statement, however, expects the condition to be either `True`, `False`, `Null`, or a numeric value (0 = falsy, all other numerals are truthy) which counts as false, not a Windows username, that's why the error occurs.

If you use `On Error Resume Next`, you're actually jumping into that `If` statement if the `DLookup` returns a string, because that's the next thing. However, if it returns `Null`, because it can't find that username, that doesn't trigger an error, because `Null` is a valid value which is cast to false.

Some sample code to help you understand this:

```
Public Sub TestIfResumeNext()
    If Null Then
        Debug.Print Null
    End If
On Error Resume Next
    If "A" Then
        Debug.Print "A"
    End If
    If 1 Then
        Debug.Print 1
    End If
    If 0 Then
        Debug.Print 0
    End If
    If -1 Then
        Debug.Print -1
    End If
End Sub
```

This will return `"A"` because of error capturing, `1` and `-1` because they're truthy, but not `Null` because that's a valid falsy value, and not `0` for that same reason.

If you don't want to rely on this error trapping behavior, but want to keep the rest of the logic, you could simply replace `DLookUp` with `DCount`. Since `0` is falsy, you don't even need to check if it's `0` (but doing so is a good practice imho).

```
If DCount("[CitrixID]", "tbl_UserAccess", "[CitrixID] = " & "'" & Environ("username") & "'") Then
```

Or, with the comparison

```
If DCount("[CitrixID]", "tbl_UserAccess", "[CitrixID] = " & "'" & Environ("username") & "'") <> 0 Then
```

Note that you can now shorten it using `If Not` or `If DCount = 0` and remove the `Else`

Answer (score 1):

DLookup returns *Null* for "not found" so all you need is to check for this:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    If IsNull(DLookup("[CitrixID]", "tbl_UserAccess", "[CitrixID] = '" & Environ("username") & "'")) Then
        MsgBox "You do not have permission to access the application."
        DoCmd.Close
    End If

End Sub
```